# Docker Build Error https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid

Tags: docker, x509certificate

When I try to run docker build, it gives me error:

```
https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.kneura.com, not registry-1.docker.io
```

I have Docker Desktop on Windows10

Answer (score 6):

I could solve this problem after deleting entry in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

```
34.228.211.243 registry-1.docker.io
```